# How to pass Ivy credentials to scripted test?

Tags: testing, sbt

I'm using [scripted test framework](http://eed3si9n.com/testing-sbt-plugins) to test a sbt plugin. As part of that test it needs to download artifacts from a private artifact store. Scripted seems to ignore the credentials in the `~/.sbt/0.13` directory. How can I get my test to use those credentials?

It would be good if I didn't have to hard code any path.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have followed [the official Publishing document](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Publishing.html#Credentials) and have a `.credentials` file containing `realm`, `host`, `user`, `password`:

```
realm=Sonatype Nexus Repository Manager
host=nexus.scala-tools.org
user=admin
password=admin123
```

Then in the `build.sbt` of your *test* add

```
credentials += Credentials(BuildPaths.defaultVersionedGlobalBase(sbtVersion.value) / "credentials")
```

Comment: This requires having a specifically named file in a specific directory.
There is no guarantee that other users will have their credentials file in that specific location. For example I have a credentials.sbt in several version directories but the actual credentials are somewhere else.
I don't really want to require someone having sbt set up in a specific way for that particular project.

Answer (score 0):

This is my hack/workaround for the problem.

In scripted.sbt I add the following code.

```
credentials ++= {
  val out = credentials.value.map {
    case c: FileCredentials   => s"""Credentials(new java.io.File("${c.path.getAbsolutePath}"))"""
    case c: DirectCredentials => s"Credentials(${c.realm}, ${c.host}, ${c.userName}, ${c.passwd})"
  }.mkString(" credentials ++= Seq(", ",", ")")
  sbtTestDirectory.value.listFiles.flatMap(_.listFiles).map(f => IO.writeLines(f / "credentials.sbt", Seq(out)))
  List()
}
```

This takes the existing sbt credentials and writes a credentials.sbt into each of the scriptet tests, e.g sbt-test/test-group/test-name/credentials.sbt. This is then used by the scripted tests.

My sbt knowledge is somewhat limited so this is a bit ugly.